# Synching offline data Rails 6 / React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, architecture

Apologies for the broad question.

Some context:

I'm about to start working in a greenfield project related to healthcare.
The stack is being established and although I might have a say on it, I can't really decide. (My expertise is on Rails(Backend), rails forms, vanilla JS / some Stimulus.js).
From what I heard my future colleagues are leaning towards Rails 6 / React.

The issue:

The users would have to go on field to interview, examine and gather data from patients around their conditions using a tablet. Sometimes simple fixed answer questions, sometimes inter-dependent questions that might trigger warnings, involve states, roles and permissions. In many occasions **they won't have internet access**.

Question:

**How would you approach this in a Rails application? Which FE technologies/frameworks/etc would you use and why?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can store these answers in local storage and mark it on interface as saved locally. And when device will have internet access - just ask user to save this data on server by clicking some button. Hope this is will help you and I correctly understand the question :)